Suppose a sequence $\{a_n\}$, $a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac1{a_n},n\in\mathbb{N}^*$, then $a_n=\sqrt{2n}+\frac{\sqrt2\ln n}{8\sqrt n}+O(\frac{\ln n}{n^{3/2}})$?
Question
Suppose a sequence $\{ a_n \}$, $a_{n+1}=a_n+\displaystyle\frac1{a_n},a_1=1,n\in\mathbb{N}^*$, then prove: $a_n=\sqrt{2n}+\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt2\ln n}{8\sqrt n}+O(\displaystyle\frac{\ln n}{n^{3/2}})$ when $n\to\infty$.
My attempt
I think this question should be divided into 3 steps.
Step 1 Prove: $a_n\sim\sqrt{2n}\ (n\to\infty)$. To achieve this, first I prove that $a_n\to+\infty$ when $n\to\infty$, then I use $\text{Stolz theorem}$ to prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n^2}{2n}=1.$
Step 2 Prove: $\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt n(a_n-\sqrt{2n})}{\ln n}\to\frac{\sqrt2}8\ (n\to\infty)$.
Because
$\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt n(a_n-\sqrt{2n})}{\ln n}=\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt n(a_n^2-2n)}{(a_n+\sqrt{2n})\ln n},$ and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt n}{a_n+\sqrt{2n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{2n}}+1}\cdot\frac1{\sqrt2}=\frac{\sqrt2}4.
$$
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n^2-2n}{\ln n}\overset{\text{Stolz}}{=}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}^2-a_n^2-2}{\ln(1+\frac1n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}n(a_{n+1}^2-a_n^2-2)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot\frac1{a_n^2}=\frac12.\quad(\ln(1+\frac1n)\sim\frac1n\ (n\to\infty))
$$
Step 3 Prove: $\displaystyle\frac{8\sqrt n(a_n-\sqrt{2n})-\sqrt2\ln n)\cdot n}{8\ln n}=O(1)\ (n\to\infty)$.
This is the part which confuses me a lot, the target seems too tricky for me, I hope someone can help me prove this.
Inspiration
When I review the progress of the proof, it is a bit like estimating the magnitude of a sequence. It reminds me of the Taylor expansion in functions. So is there a similar expansion in sequences, or where do these terms come from? I think this can give me a deeper insight into this kind of questions.
Any sort of help is welcomed!

Was $a_1$ mentioned in the question?

if $x_n=a_n^2$ then
$$
x_{n+1}=x_n+2+\frac1{x_n}
$$
Let $x_n=y_n+2n$. Then
$$
y_{n+1}=y_n+\frac1{y_n+2n}
$$
Assume w.l.o.g. $y_1=0$ (a general case can be handles similarly).  Then $y_n\uparrow$ and
$$
y_n\le \frac12\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\dots+\frac1{n-1}\right)\sim \frac{\ln n}2=o(n)
$$
hence for large $n$
$$
y_{n+1}=y_n+\frac{1+o(1)}{2n}
$$
and thus $y_n\sim \frac{\ln n}2$.
This already gives
$$
x_n=2n+(1+o(1))\frac{\ln n}2
$$
which gives you the first two terms of $a_n=\sqrt{x_n}$.
Estimating the error term shouldn't e very difficult now.
